# Heroku timezone difference rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, timezone

i have problem with heroku timezone

heroku:

```
 Time.zone.now
    => Tue, 16 Dec 2014 14:41:57 MSK +04:00
```

but on localhost is

```
Time.zone.now
=> Tue, 16 Dec 2014 13:41:01 MSK +03:00
```

where is the problem?

im already did `heroku config:add TZ="my TZ"`

in application.rb

```
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.generators do |g|
     config.time_zone = 'Moscow'
  g.orm :mongo_mapper
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such TZ name is Moscow it should be `Europe/Moscow`

```
heroku config:add TZ = "Europe/Moscow"
```

Please refer this link to all the available Time zone

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Also for more details

https://coderwall.com/p/j9_e8a/set-timezone-for-your-heroku-app

Comment: under tz i meant city,i tried different variation but no luck